# Remove default warning message Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the google maps API and have created a route finder using the Directions Service method. However, by default it comes with the warning message above the travel route:

***Walking directions are in beta. Use caution – This route may be missing sidewalks or pedestrian paths.***

Is there a way of removing this message?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I inspected the warning box element and found the css classes it belonged to. I then added them to my style sheet with the following attributes:

```
.warnbox-content,.adp-warnbox{
visibility:hidden;
height:0;
width:0;

}
```